# Какие возможные паттерны могу быть у HTTP-заголовка HOST?

Tags: http, http-заголовки

Мне нужно извлечь поддомен из HTTP-заголовка HOST без использования библиотек. В общем случае это будет что-то вроде `developer.mozilla.org` и тут всё довольно просто: разбиваем строку точкой `.` на массив и убираем последние два элемента (даже не важно на каком языке).

Но согласно [MDN документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host), HTTP-заголовок HOST может иметь вид `<host>:<port>`. Но я его в таком виде ни разу не видел. Если это будет что-то вроде `http://developer.localhost:3000/`, то приведённый выше алгоритм не подойдёт.

Итак, чтобы успешно справиться с приведённой выше задачей, необходимо знать, какие возможные паттерны могут быть у HTTP-заголовка HOST, что я бы и хотел узнать в данном вопросе.

Comment: Согласно RFC 7230 только эти два варианта и возможны

Comment: Благодарю Вас за комментарий! Значит значение `http://developer.localhost:3000/` - валидное?

Comment: Нет, такого значения Host быть не может, бывает только `developer.localhost:3000`

Comment: Хорошо, значит это ответ.